# FileInputStream and Huffman Tree

Tags: java, fileinputstream, huffman-code

I am creating a Huffman tree to compress a text file but I am having some issues. This method I am making is supposed to take a `FileInputStream` which inputs the text data and returns a `Map` of the characters and the counts. However, to do that, I need to define the size of `byte[]` to store the data. The problem is that the `byte[]` array size needs to be just the right length or else the `Map` will also have some unneeded data. Is there a way to make the `byte[]` just the right size?

Here is my code:

```
// provides a count of characters in an input file and place in map
public static Map<Character, Integer> getCounts(FileInputStream input)
        throws IOException {
    Map<Character, Integer> output = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>(); // treemap keeps keys in sorted order (chars alphabetized)
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[100]; // creates a byte[]
    //ArrayList<Byte> test = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    input.read(fileContent);                // reads the input into fileContent
    String test = new String(fileContent);  // contains entire file into this string to process

    // goes through each character of String to put chars as keys and occurrences as keys
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        char temp = test.charAt(i);
        if (output.containsKey(temp)) { // seen this character before; increase count

            int count = output.get(temp);
            System.out.println("repeat; char is: " + temp + "count is: " + count);
            output.put(temp, count + 1);
        } else {                        // Haven't seen this character before; create count of 1
            System.out.println("new; char is: " + temp + "count is: 1");
            output.put(temp, 1);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `FileInputStream.read()` is the number of bytes actually read, or `-1` in case of EOF. You can use  this value instead of `test.length()` in the *for* loop.

Notice that `read()` is not guaranteed to read in the buffer length worth of bytes, even if the end of file is not reached, so it is usually used in a loop:

```
int bytesRead;

//Read until there is no more bytes to read.
while((bytesRead = input.read(buf))!=-1)
{
    //You have next bytesRead bytes in a buffer here      
}
```

Finally, if your strings are Unicode, this approach will not work, since `read()` can terminate mid-character. Consider using `InputStreamReader` to wrap `FileInputStream`:

```
Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");

int charsRead;
char buf[] = new char[256];

while ((charsRead = fileReader.read(buf)) > 0) {
   //You have charsRead characters in a buffer here
}
```